# Соотнесённость местоимения и существительного, на которое оно указывает

Tags: синтаксис, местоимения, местоимение

**Деталь соединена цепью с ободом, что делает невозможным её изъятие.**

Если смотреть на предложение логически, то понятно, что "её" указывает на слово "деталь". Но в единственном числе стоит ещё одно существительное женского рода — "цепь", поэтому чисто синтаксически местоимение "её" можно отнести и к слову "цепь".

Два вопроса:

1) Можно ли по литературным нормам оставлять такую чисто синтаксическую двоякость понимания, когда логически всё ясно? Или правильно абсолютно всегда избегать это?

2) В русском языке при прочих равных условиях местоимение относится к ближайшему предшествующему слову, стоящему в том же роде и числе? Или оно может быть отнесено к любому из них исходя из смысла ситуации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта "двоякость" мнимая, машинно-алгоритмическая. Ни один носитель языка не отнесёт здесь местоимение к цепи: поняв всё сразу, он не станет анализировать, что, какого грамматического рода и в каких количествах встречается. И дело не в логике, указывающей на деталь. Придаточное предложение здесь акцентируется не на дополнении "цепи" а в целом на суждении, высказанном в первой части предложения ("что" относится ко всему ранее сказанному), поэтому внимание фокусируется на подлежащем и сказуемом, и сразу находится "деталь". Двоякость смыслов не возникнет даже при изменённом порядке слов:

> Деталь соединена с ободом цепью, что делает невозможным её изъятие.

Чтобы как-то привязать вторую часть предложения к цепи, нужны отдельные средства:

> Деталь соединена с ободом именно этой цепью, что делает невозможным её изъятие.

Но в этом случае смысл будет зависеть от контекста. Если перед этим речь шла о том, что некую цепь в разных конструкциях нужно периодически извлекать для смазки, то предложение воспринимается как пример расположения цепи в механизме и добавленный акцент "именно этой" свяжет невозможность изъятия с "цепью". Если же говорилось о детали, а цепь просто упоминалась, то "невозможность" и здесь будет отнесена "детали", а добавленный к цепи акцент будет восприниматься просто как ссылка на упоминавшееся. И лишь в случае, когда предложение лишено контекста, а вам нужно однозначно отнести придаточное предложение к "**цепи**" (например, в юридически значимой формулировке, которая требует защиты от попыток иного толкования), предложение нужно перестроить, привязав придаточную часть к нужному слову:

> Деталь соединена с ободом цепью, изъятие которой по этой причине
>   невозможно.

Comment: Можно даже не перестраивать, а воспользоваться кавычками: «Деталь соединена цепью с ободом, что делает невозможным её [цепи/детали] изъятие».

Comment: Так можно, но при явном повторном указании естественнее убрать местоимение и поставить существительное в конце.

Comment: @Aer Вы о кавычках или о скобках?

Comment: Спасибо за столь развёрнутый ответ. Не могли бы вы дать ответ на мой второй вопрос о том, к какому слову местоимение относится в общем случае? То, что в случае дополнения и пояснения придаточным всего главного предложения при отнесении местоимения отдаётся предпочтение подлежащему, мне понятно.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко, Создается впечатление,что Вы хотите получить алгоритм для компьютера.